# Logon failed for login 'username' due to trigger execution with node-mssql

Tags: node.js, node-mssql

I'm using `node-mssql` with `tedious` as the driver (default one) for connecting to mssql server.

I have no problem connecting to a dev server when when connecting to one of the production server, i got this error

```
Logon failed for login 'username' due to trigger execution.
```

I can connect to this server just fine using any SQL client (mssql, dbeaver, ...).

The code i use for connecting is pretty much the default example

```
var conn = new sql.Connection(db_conf, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    deferred.reject(new Error('Unable to connect, err ' + err));
  } else {
    deferred.resolve(conn);
  }
});
```

Any idea why this happened?

Comment: Can you show an example of your conn string?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin the connection conf is like the default one on `tedious`'s [github page](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) with username, passwd, ip and db name, default driver (tedious) and default port 1433. I double check the info and was able to connect to the server using mssql client.

Comment: Refer : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/27/sql-server-fix-error-17892-logon-failed-for-login-due-to-trigger-execution-changed-database-context-to-master/

Comment: @bgs isaw it earlier when searching for problem. though i don't have full permission on the server. Also, why didn't i have problem when connecting to it using a GUI client.